# JSON to POJO - Ignore certain nested properties

Tags: java, json, xml, jersey, pojo

Suppose I have a JSON object that looks like this

```
{
  "name":"John",
  "age":30,
  "someAttribute1": {
      "property1":"example1",
      "property2":"example2"
  },
  "someAttribute2": {
      "property1":"example1",
      "property2":"example2"
  }
}
```

And the following POJO class to read that entity into

```
@XmlRootElement      
public class Person {
  @XmlElement(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @XmlElement(name = "age")
  private int age;
}
```

How can I get the `property1` field of `someAttribute1` and the `property1` field of `someAttribute2`, without having to create a separate class representation for `somAttribute1` and `someAttribute2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do this is by using `Map<KeyType, ValueType>` for example in your case a `Map<String, String>` will do the work. The code should work like that:

```
@XmlRootElement      
public class Person {
  @XmlElement(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @XmlElement(name = "age")
  private int age;

  @XmlElement(name = "someAttribute2")
  private Map<String, String> someAttributeTwo;

  @XmlElement(name = "someAttribute1")
  private Map<String, String> someAttributeOne;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example what seems to fit your case is add two hashmap member variables in your Person class like below:

```
@XmlRootElement      
public class Person {
@XmlElement(name = "name")
private String name;

@XmlElement(name = "age")
private int age;
}

@XmlElement(name = "someAttribute1")
private HashMap<String,String> someAttribute1;
}

@XmlElement(name = "someAttribute2")
private HashMap<String,String> someAttribute2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson library to unpack the nested property by using a combination of `@JsonProperty` and some custom logic in your class.

```
    public class Person {
      private String name;
      private int age;
      private String someAttribute1Property1;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @JsonProperty("someAttribute1")
    private void unpackNested(Map<String,Object> someAttribute1) {
        this.someAttribute1= (String)brand.get("Property1");
       -------
    }
}
```

Reference : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values